# Message lost on a long delivery path using java nio

Tags: java, message, nio

In my project, a sequence of messages are forwarded from A to B to ... to K. The delivery path is 11 nodes. The socket is java nio. The problem is that some messages are lost and not received at the last node. What is the reason of this exception? Thanks.

---

I am using TCP and only use java nio library. The exception: for example, at the starting node, there is 2999 messages published. At the ending node, there is 2995 messages received. Several messages are lost along the delivery path.

If I send the message very fast, eg, the interval time is 50 ms, the number of loss messages are increasing.

How to debug this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: You need to provide more information.  Are you using streams (TCP) or datagrams (UDP)?  Are you using some 3rd-party messaging framework, or have you implemented your own?  What is the exception you are getting?  Do you know which "hop" the messages are getting lost at?

Answer (score 2):

I solve this problem by checking the number of bytes written. If there is 0 byte written, I will rewrite it again. The writing process ends when there is no remaining bytes in the byte buffer.

Comment: Yes, it is important to note that SocketChannel.write(), if in non-blocking mode, might not write everything at once. It might also write only some parts of the message (instead of nothing or the whole one).